# Javascript - first occurence of class, multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to retrieve the first occurrence of a given class inside another class that is repeated a couple of times inside the page. Let's use an example to make it easier:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    aaaa
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    bbbb
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    cccc
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    dddd
    </div>
    <div class="otherclass">
    eeee
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    ffff
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    gggg
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    hhhh
    </div>
    <div class="otherclass">
    iiii
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    jjjj
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    kkkk
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to retrieve the value inside the first occurrence of "test" inside each "row". I could use "each" to go through each div with "row" but I'd like to avoid that as I need to apply the same code to there pages that don't need a "each".

I've tried :first or :first-child but the problem is that test is not always at the same position.

The result of this should be an array with:

bbbb

ffff

jjjj

Any idea of how I could do this without "each" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically don't want to use `each()` you can use `map()`, although the looping logic is pretty much identical. It's just that `map()` is more succinct when creating arrays.

```js
var foo = $('.row').find('.test:first').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="otherclass">aaaa</div>
  <div class="test">bbbb</div>
  <div class="test">cccc</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="otherclass">dddd</div>
  <div class="otherclass">eeee</div>
  <div class="test">ffff</div>
  <div class="test">gggg</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="otherclass">hhhh</div>
  <div class="otherclass">iiii</div>
  <div class="test">jjjj</div>
  <div class="test">kkkk</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`find(".test:first")` should do it. My provided solution uses an each loop, but I see no problem in using one.

```js
$.each($(".row"), (i, obj)=>{
  console.log($(obj).find(".test:first").html())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    aaaa
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    bbbb
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    cccc
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    dddd
    </div>
    <div class="otherclass">
    eeee
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    ffff
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    gggg
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    hhhh
    </div>
    <div class="otherclass">
    iiii
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    jjjj
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    kkkk
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with jQuery's `each()` along with `:first` selector:

```js
var res = [];
$('.row').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).find('.test:first').text().trim();
  res.push(text);
});
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    aaaa
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    bbbb
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    cccc
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    dddd
    </div>
    <div class="otherclass">
    eeee
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    ffff
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    gggg
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="otherclass">
    hhhh
    </div>
    <div class="otherclass">
    iiii
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    jjjj
    </div>
    <div class="test">
    kkkk
    </div>
</div>
```